# Bind width on UI element to Width of another UI Element

Tags: wpf, data-binding, width

I wanted to bind `Width` of a column header to the `Width` of the header defined. However the code doesn't work. If I specify the `Width` explicitly (Width="100"), it works fine. Can someone shed some light and tell me what is wrong with the code below?

```
<dataGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="pdpCol" Width="100">
        <dataGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <TextBlock Text="PDP" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="{Binding ElementName=pdpCol,Path=ActualWidth }" TextAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
        </dataGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
</dataGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 6):

Remove the `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` from the TextBlock or set the property to `Stretch`. Then the TextBlock will consume all available width automatically. Furthermore, if you don't show anything else than the textblock, then remove the grid and use just the TextBlock. You also need to set HeaderTemplate rather the Header directly.

```
<dataGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="pdpCol" Width="100" Header="PDP">
    <dataGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextAlign="Center" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </dataGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
</dataGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Best Regards,
Oliver Hanappi

Answer (score 1):

Try the markup below. Please note the use of `HeaderStyle` to stretch the template and `HeaderTemplate` to actually define the visual template for your `Header="PDP"` item.

```
<dataGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="pdpCol" Width="100" Header="PDP">
    <dataGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type Primitives:DataGridColumnHeader}">
              <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
              <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
         </Style>
    </dataGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
    <dataGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextAlignment="Center" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </dataGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
</dataGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if `ActualWidth` is being set, I think it will work if you just use `Path=Width`.

Comment: FYI - that is, in general, incorrect.  ActualWidth is always (automatically) set on a UIElement, and is readonly.  It is, oddly enough, the actual width of the UIElement.  The Width property may or may not be set.

Comment: I have had cases where ActualWidth was null while Width was the correct value. In scenarios very similar as in the question posted.